# Recognizing subexpressions when parsing a string in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I am trying to `simplify` a rather complicated expression in sympy.

```
from sympy import *
xi, eta = symbols('xi eta')
expr = (sin(eta)*sin(xi) - 1)**2*(sin(eta)*sin(xi) + 1)**2/((cos(eta)**2*tan(xi)**2 + 1)*(cos(xi)**2*tan(eta)**2 + 1)*cos(eta)**2*cos(xi)**2)
```

`expr` should simplify to `1`, but sympy fails to do so automatically. In order to help it a little, I need a change of variables:

```
X, Y = symbols('X Y')
xi = atan(X)
eta = atan(Y)
```

So `xi`, and `eta` are not symbols anymore. Now I need to re-parse `expr` in order to change the variables. What I currently do is:

```
simplify(repr(expr).replace('xi',repr(xi)).replace('eta', repr(eta)))
```

This works. But it seems like a crude way of doing it. Is there any other way for sympy ro recognize that `xi` and `eta` are expressions and not symbols, when parsing `repr(expr)`.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sympify` (or `S` for short) will convert a string to an expression, and it has an option to make user-defined replacements while doing so. This toy example should help you:

```
>>> from sympy import S, cos
>>> from sympy.abc import x
S('x',dict(x=cos(x)))
cos(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @mapf mentioned in the comments, substitution (`expr.subs`) could be used:

```
from sympy import *
xi, eta = symbols('xi eta')
expr = (sin(eta)*sin(xi) - 1)**2*(sin(eta)*sin(xi) + 1)**2/((cos(eta)**2*tan(xi)**2 + 1)*(cos(xi)**2*tan(eta)**2 + 1)*cos(eta)**2*cos(xi)**2)

X, Y = symbols('X Y')
simplify( expr.subs( [(xi, atan(X)), (eta, atan(Y))] ) )
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution that you're happy with, although that was actually not what I was talking about. I literally meant *writing out your expr using `atan(X)` and `atan(Y)`*: `expr = (sin(atan(Y))*sin(atan(X)) - 1)**2*(sin(atan(Y))*sin(atan(X)) + 1)**2/((cos(atan(Y))**2*tan(atan(X))**2 + 1)*(cos(atan(X))**2*tan(atan(Y))**2 + 1)*cos(atan(Y))**2*cos(atan(X))**2`

Comment: Well, what I was doing above was that exactly. But doing that would be difficult if the symbols were too simple like `a` and `b`. One would need to use regex to get the job done and it would still be prone to errors.